# FileUpload HasFile returns false

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I know that this issue is common however in my case, I'm involving a javascript so that could be the problem. Here's what I'm doing. I'm calling the asp FileUpload to allow the user to select an image. Then by calling the onchange event, I'm firing a javascript which in turn makes a hidden div become visible. The div contains a Confirm button, which then fires the upload function:

```
<div class="profile-page-owner-profile-pic">
       <asp:FileUpload ID="profile_pic_input" onchange="profilenewimageinput(this)" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
</div>
```

Hidden Div:

```
<div id="profile-change-profile-pic-bg-overlay-div">
     <div class="profile-change-profile-pic-bottom-bar"> 
          <asp:Button ID="picApply" class="cropButton" runat="server" OnClick="picApply_Click" Text="Button" />
          <span class="profile-page-cancel-crop-button" onclick="hideprofilepicwindow()">Cancel</span> 
      </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function profilenewimageinput() {

    document.getElementById("profile-change-profile-pic-bg-overlay-div").style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function () {

        document.getElementById("profile-change-profile-pic-bg-overlay-div").style.opacity = 1;

    }, 100);

}
```

Code behind:

```
protected void picApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (profile_pic_input.HasFile) //always returns false when debugged
     {
          //Code
     }
}
```

Why is my HasFile always returning False even when an Image is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` with an appropriate `Trigger` setup. The following may work, but I'm not in a place to test:

```
<div class="profile-page-owner-profile-pic">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UploadPanel" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="picApply" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="profile_pic_input" onchange="profilenewimageinput(this)" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
</div>
```